# Linux, C++ Pipes and Forking (Timeout and Read)

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork

I have a parent process which starts a child process (using fork) that constantly outputs  lots of data to std::cout.

This child creats lots of data so I want to be constantly be calling read() so that I get this data (according to the docs if the pipe gets full the child will block). I also want to sigkill the child after a time-out elapses.

To achieve the above goal, the parent will fork an other child that basically calls **sigtimedwait** and kills the first child-process when the time-out elapses. In the mean time the parent will call read() to get the data from the first child.

This works well, apart from one big issue, when the time-out elapses (in the time-out process) and sigkill is issued, the parent remains blocked for ever on the read() function call!!! (I assume this happens since pipe isn't closed)

I have two questions.

1. Is this the corret way of doing things in Linux to achieve my goal? (i.e implement timeout mechanism and read data from in 'real time')
2. If so, how can I solve the aforementioned issue?

Thanks!

Comment: _"I guess I have two questions."_ Do you have questions or not?

Comment: MCVE needed - from the description, when the first child gets killed its end of the pipe should be closed which should cause an EOF on the other end of the pipe.  It's possible the parent isn't properly closing its handle to the write end of the pipe, though.

Comment: @DanielSchepler you are correct, this fixed the problem! Thanks!.  Is there a more effceint way doing what I descripted in questions? Spawning two processes seems inefficient to me.